# multiple nested to one relationship in jooq

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I'm using JOOQ 3.17.6 with Kotlin and can't figure out how can I retrieve and populate A->B->C relationships.

Given some classes Foo->Bar->Baz

```
data class Foo(
  val fooName: String,
  val bar: Bar
)

data class Bar(
  val barName: String,
  val baz: Baz
)

data class Baz(
  val bazName: String
)
```

If I want to retrieve only `Bar` it can be done fairly easy

```
context.select(
  BAR.barName,
  BAR.baz().as("baz")
).from(BAR)
  .where(BAR.barName.eq("first"))
  fetchOneInto(Bar::class.java)
```

The issue I have is to do the same when I want to fetch full tree Foo->Bar->Baz. The following code will fail as `baz` for `Bar` class is not populated as obviously JOOQ does not know where to get it.

```
context.select(
  Foo.fooName,
  FOO.bar().as("bar")
).from(FOO)
  .where(FOO.fooName.eq("first"))
  .fetchOneInto(Foo::class.java)
```

I could do something like described here https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.17/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/ and then the query will look like

```
context.select(
  FOO, 
  FOO.bar(), 
  FOO.bar().baz()
).where(FOO.fooName.eq("first"))
  .fetch()
  .map { /* do actual mapping here */ }
```

but if entities are more complicated with 4-5-6 references each having 10+ fields, then this mapping becomes quite tedious.

Another way would be to keep ids instead of domain types on entities, i.e.

```
data class Foo(
  val name: String,
  val barId: String
)
```

and do DB calls when we actually need referenced entities, but as we are moving from Hibernate, this kind of change would require more work than desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using reflection

Your initial attempts show that you're fine with using the reflection based approach to mapping data, so you can just continue doing that. It will be the simplest, but lacking type safety, there is risk of error.

```kotlin
context.select(
  Foo.fooName,
  FOO.bar().as("bar"),
  FOO.bar().baz().as("bar.baz") // This is the magic
).from(FOO)
  .where(FOO.fooName.eq("first"))
  .fetchOneInto(Foo::class.java)
```

This is using the [`Settings.namePathSeparator`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#namePathSeparator) token (by default a `"."`) to work out the path of nested objects in the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html). As per the Javadoc:

> If `Field.getName()` is `MY_field.MY_nested_field` (case-sensitive!), then this field's value will be considered a nested value `MY_nested_field`, which is set on a nested POJO

### Using type safe mappers

If you want type safety, you have to mimick the target data structure also in your query, e.g.

```kotlin
context.select(
  FOO.NAME,
  // List all of Foo's columns here
  row(
    FOO.bar().NAME,
    // List all of Bar's columns here
    row(
      FOO.bar().baz().NAME
      // List all of Baz's columns here
    ).mapping(::Baz)
  ).mapping(::Bar)
).from(FOO)
  .where(FOO.fooName.eq("first"))
  .fetchOne(Records.mapping(::Foo))
```

Of course, you could also add one more level of nesting by projecting `FOO.bar()` and `FOO.bar().baz()`, to avoid listing columns individually, but only if your target data structure also nests things this way.

This is a great reminder to ask yourself if you really need to project *all* the columns, or if listing columns explicitly might not be the better approach here from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the approach with `namePathSeparator` from the previous answer in Java and it doesn't work.

I will try to explain what's happening in my application using previous example. If I write query this way

```
context.select(FOO.FOO_NAME,
           FOO.bar().as("bar"),
           FOO.bar().baz().as("bar.baz"))
.from(FOO)
 .where(FOO.FOO_NAME.eq("first"))
 .fetchOneInto(Foo.class);
```

I get following result:

- `bar.baz` is null
- `baz` attributes override `bar` attributes of the same name (e.g. `bar.id` value is overridden by `baz.id`)
- other `bar` attributes have `NULL` values

I am using jOOQ 3.17.5, but I also tried with 3.18.3.