# jOOQ multiple levels of nesting

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

I am trying to fetch complex structure from the database using jOOQ. I will try to explain on an example where the problem is.

So, let's imagine we have classes Foo, Bar and Bazz:

```
public class Foo {
    private String fooName;
    private List<Bar> bars;
}

public class Bar {
    private Bazz bazz;
}

public class Bazz {
    private String name;
}
```

I want to fetch and populate Foo -> List<Bar> -> Bazz relationship.

I tried with `MULTISET` and it works, but I want to avoid subqueries. I want to fetch and map that using `JOIN`. I wonder if it is possible to fetch that using reflection, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75723738/7840215).

Here is an example with `MULTISET` :

```
public List<FooResponse> findByFooName(String fooName) {
        return ctx().select(FOO.asterisk(),
                        multiset(select(BAR.asterisk(),
                                BAR.bazz().as("bazz"))
                              .from(BAR)
                              .where(BAR.FOO_ID.eq(FOO.ID))).as("bars"))
        .from(FOO)
        .where(FOO.FOO_NAME.eq(fooName))
        .fetchInto(FooResponse.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a little research and found several solutions to the aforementioned problem.

1. Using multiset() -> the previous example

   - PROS:

     - least verbose way
     - Java part is pretty simple if you know what you are doing
   - CONS:

     - besides knowing SQL, you'll have to research how `DSL.multiset()` works
     - you have to use subselect
     - the generated SQL might look very complicated, probably hard to debug
2. Using multisetAgg()

   ```
   return ctx().select(FOO.ID,
                       FOO.FOO_NAME,
                       multisetAgg(
                               BAR.ID,
                               row(BAR.bazz().ID,
                                       BAR.bazz().NAME
                               ).mapping(Bazz::new),
                               BAR.SOME_ATTRIBUTE,
                               BAR.SOME_OTHER_ATTRIBUTE
                       ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Bar::new))).as("bars"),
                       FOO.CREATED_AT,
                       FOO.MODIFIED_AT
               )
               .from(FOO)
               .join(BAR).on(BAR.FOO_ID.eq(FOO.ID))
               .groupBy(FOO.ID)
               .having(FOO.FOO_NAME.eq(fooName))
               .fetchInto(Foo.class);
   ```

   - PROS:

     - still looks pretty simple
     - you don't have to use subselect
   - CONS:

     - besides knowing SQL, you'll have to research how `DSL.multisetAgg()` works
     - the order of the columns in the `SELECT` statement must match the order of the parameters in constructors
     - the generated SQL might look very complicated, probably hard to debug
3. Using [modelmapper](https://modelmapper.org/)

   ```
   @Bean
   public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
       var modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
       modelMapper.getConfiguration()
               .addValueReader(new RecordValueReader())
               .setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE);
       return modelMapper;
   }
   ```

   ```
   return ctx().select(FOO.asterisk(),
                           BAR.asterisk(),
                           BAZZ.asterisk()
                   )
                   .from(FOO)
                   .join(BAR).on(BAR.FOO_ID.eq(FOO.ID))
                   .join(BAZZ).on(BAZZ.ID.eq(BAR.BAZZ_ID))
                   .where(FOO.FOO_NAME.eq(fooName))
                   .orderBy(FOO.ID, BAR.ID)
                   .collect(groupingBy(
                           r -> modelMapper.map(r.into(FOO), Foo.class), filtering(
                                   r -> r.get(BAR.ID) != null, mapping(
                                           r -> new Pair(modelMapper.map(r.into(BAR), Bar.class),
                                                   modelMapper.map(r.into(BAZZ), Bazz.class)),
                                           toList()
                                   )
                           )
                   ))
                   .entrySet().stream().map(o -> {
                       var foo = o.getKey();
                       return foo.setBars(o.getValue().stream().map(v -> {
                           var bar = (Bar) v.getValue0();
                           var bazz = (Bazz) v.getValue1();
                           return bar.setBazz(bazz);
                       }).toList());
                   }).toList();
   ```

   - PROS:

     - 1:1 equivalence between SQL syntax and the jOOQ API
   - CONS:

     - pretty verbose
     - easy to mess up (manual grouping and mapping)
     - external library
4. Using [SimpleFlatMapper](https://simpleflatmapper.org/0106-getting-started-jooq.html)

   ```
   private final JdbcMapper<Foo> fooResponseJdbcMapper;

   public FooRepository(...) {
       this.fooResponseJdbcMapper = JdbcMapperFactory.newInstance()
               .addKeys("id")
               .ignorePropertyNotFound()
               .newMapper(Foo.class);
       }
   .
   .
   .
   public List<Foo> findByCustomerId(Long id) {
       try (var result = ctx().select(FOO.ID,
                           FOO.FOO_NAME,
                           FOO.CREATED_AT,
                           FOO.MODIFIED_AT,
                           BAR.ID.as("bars_id"),
                           BAR.SOME_ATTRIBUTE.as("bars_some_attribute"),
                           BAR.SOME_OTHER_ATTRIBUTE.as("bars_some_other_attribute"),
                           BAZZ.ID.as("bars_bazz_id"),
                           BAZZ.NAME.as("bars_bazz_name")
                   )
                   .from(FOO)
                   .join(BAR).on(BAR.FOO_ID.eq(FOO.ID))
                   .join(BAZZ).on(BAZZ.ID.eq(BAR.BAZZ_ID))
                   .where(FOO.FOO_NAME.eq(fooName))
                   .orderBy(FOO.ID, BAR.ID)
                   .fetchResultSet()) {
               return fooResponseJdbcMapper.stream(result).toList();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   ```

   - PROS:

     - 1:1 equivalence between SQL syntax and the jOOQ API
     - looks pretty simple
   - CONS:

     - external library
     - you have to assign aliases to selected columns if you want SimpleFlatMapper to map everything correctly

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, you can nest with `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` / [`MULTISET_AGG`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/), instead of using the [`MULTISET` value constructor](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/), because you're nesting only one level of nested collections (the second nesting is not a collection). The main difference will be what happens when you don't have any `BAR` for a `FOO`. With aggregation, this produces a `NULL` value, not an empty collection.

However, there are a few limitations in the API (e.g. [#15008](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15008), [#15007](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15007), [#13937](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13937)) making this a bit difficult using the `DefaultRecordMapper` (the `fetchInto(X.class)` call). Here's a solution using [ad-hoc conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) and type safety:

```java
ctx().select(
        FOO.FOO_NAME,
        multisetAgg(

          // Add more BAR columns here, if needed
          row(

            // Add more BAZZ columns here, if needed
            BAR.bazz().NAME
          ).mapping(Bazz::new)
        ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Bar::new)))
      )
     .from(FOO)
     .join(BAR).on(BAR.FOO_ID.eq(FOO.ID))
     .groupBy(FOO.ID)
     .where(FOO.FOO_NAME.eq(fooName))
     .fetch(Records.mapping(Foo::new));
```

This is assuming you have the relevant constructors. If you don't, you can always revert to `into(X.class)` calls on each level.

One of the benefits of using [jOOQ's code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/) is that you have type safe nested collection mapping as shown above.

Comment: Thank you. I like this solution better than the one with `MULTISET`, but I don't like JSON functions in a query. It is a lot more difficult to debug that query if something goes wrong. Besides, I believe that most developers are not familiar with JSON functions in SQL. Thanks again :)

Comment: Also, if I'm right, the columns in `SELECT` have to be in the same order as the corresponding parameters in the constructor and I would like to avoid constructors with lots of parameters.

Comment: @nogalo: It's hard to provide a meaningful answer when you say: "I don't like A, and I also don't like B, and god, please don't get me started on C". I don't understand the goal you're trying to achieve here. jOOQ has support for tons of SQL functionality, and emulates standard SQL `MULTISET` using JSON (because e.g. PostgreSQL doesn't support it). jOOQ also supports `ARRAY` and `ARRAY_AGG`, etc. But what is it really that you want? Perhaps, better ask a new, very specific question that will (might) have a clear answer?

Comment: @nogalo: I mean, maybe this blog post has an answer for you? https://blog.jooq.org/using-jdk-collectors-to-de-duplicate-parent-child-nested-collections/

Comment: Actually, the question was whether it is possible to solve the problem I have using reflection, like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75722630/multiple-nested-to-one-relationship-in-jooq/75723738#75723738 and not "how to solve this problem".
I expected "Yes" or "No"  as an answer, and if "Yes", then explanation. Apparently, it's not possible, so the answer could simply be "no" :)

Comment: @nogalo: I don't understand the problem you have, sorry. You don't want to use a number of features for a variety of reasons, but that makes it hard to give you a meaningful answer. I believe my answer really answers what you have asked originally, but from your comments, apparently, you have a very different question. Probably best ask a new one?

Comment: Again, the question was whether it's possible to fetch and populate that nested structure using reflection like in OneToOne example from the link or not. I am trying out jOOQ because I like the idea of 1:1 equivalence between SQL syntax and the jOOQ API, as you mentioned here (https://foojay.io/today/5-great-reasons-to-use-jooq/), but my case is obviously way too complicated for that. I think there is no need for a new question because the answer is apparently that it is not possible to get what I want using reflection.

Comment: @nogalo: It's perfectly possible. I mentioned a few flaws that need to be worked around (and I don't want to document the workarounds, rather, I've already fixed the flaws). But what I still don't understand: why do you want to avoid `MULTISET`? There's no way to correctly normalise and deduplicate any flat results that were created with *arbitrary* joins. The whole point of `MULTISET` is to be able to nest collections *correctly* in SQL. All `JOIN` approaches are just workarounds (leading to cross products, etc.), and that has nothing to do with reflection.

Comment: I will consider using `MULTISET`. Moreover, I have already solved the problem using `MULTISET`, but I was just wondering what are alternatives to it.

Comment: @nogalo: I see. Perhaps this article is helpful to better understanding the benefits of `MULTISET`? https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/

Comment: I've made a little research and found several solutions to the aforementioned problem. There are probably more solutions to that problem, I just wrote the ones I found